# Which hierarchical model for menu and categories is used in CMS like Joomla or WP?

Tags: wordpress, database-design, joomla, hierarchical-data

Adjaceny or Nested sets model or something else?

I am interested in CMS like Joomla or WordPress and how they deal with menus, categories and other hierarchical datas that are stored in db.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can only really speak to Joomla, but you may be looking for something of this nature: http://docs.joomla.org/Using_nested_sets . I have used this to add nested sets to custom Joomla extensions that I build. This is the basis for the categories section for sure and I think the menu as well.

Comment: Categories, menus, user groups

Comment: Hmm, guys I was expecting something more ;(

Comment: Kind of dissapointed that nobody wnats to share more on this topic ;(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joomla is using nested sets for multiple things, including menu items and categories.

Wordpress seems to use a rather unusal system, storing its menu items along with other things in its "terms" table. I can only find a "parent" field there, so I'm assuming it's just simply storing the id of the parent item to model hierarchical menus. I haven't worked with Wordpress though.

Comment: That's all I've ever been able to conclude also. WP seems to work similarly to Joomla 1.5 i.e. a simple parent/child structure without the lft rgt fields for nested sets.  Joomla uses nested sets implemented in JTableNested.

Answer (score 3):

I am working with wordpress. I find model hierarchical menus in wordpress. It store the menu in db in hierarchical way. You can also find the parent menu by the wordpress function. In wordpress i can find one issues of bredcumb. If that will solved later, than wordpress menu is better than joomla.

Comment: please, provide more details.

Comment: You can get more info from http://mbaierl.com/2012/04/hierarchical-wordpress-pages-menu.html and http://mbaierl.com/2012/04/hierarchical-wordpress-pages-menu.html